Playwright doesn't load flatmates.com.au
I have been trying to create a small Playwright bot to automate answering my messages in Flatmates.com.au. When Playwright tries to navigate to the site it doesn't even load. Any ideas on how to fix that?
I tried setting different headers to make it as similar as the headers a normal user would send when making a request, but I haven't been successful.
This is what my code currently look like:
const { chromium } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://flatmates.com.au');
    await page.waitForSelector('text=Search rooms and housemates');
    await browser.close();
})();


Thanks. Looks like the page is blocking automation. Sometimes running headfully or adding a human user agent works, but that's apparently not enough here. You might want to show your other headers attempts so we can evaluate what you've tried.
